# Flutter Google maps problem not rendering the whole map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I tried to copy a project from another project in Androidstudio. I (think) I also setup the google maps (with a new API key) correctly but it is not working. I edited AndroidManifest with the new key and also the IOS Runner AppDelegate.swift in the new project. I have no error what I can see inte project and it builds fine. The below is from the Run in AndroidStudio when I run and zoom out the map. If I zoom out anymore the map just disapears.

The picture below is from when I zoom out the map and nothing more than a specific area is rendered. I cannot figure this one out? Can it be something with the API-key?

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(25851): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
I/OpenGLRenderer(25851): Davey! duration=1506ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=157629336620554, Vsync=157630719953832, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=157630736667300, AnimationStart=157630736709700, PerformTraversalsStart=157630737594900, DrawStart=157630746634600, SyncQueued=157630751622100, SyncStart=157630752322500, IssueDrawCommandsStart=157630752449000, SwapBuffers=157630764883500, FrameCompleted=157630843830600, DequeueBufferDuration=22528000, QueueBufferDuration=277000,
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53602/gl2ZeG4JgIQ=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
D/eglCodecCommon(25851): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/zzbz    (25851): Making Creator dynamically
W/tter_hunte(25851): Unsupported class loader
W/tter_hunte(25851): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule(25851): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:202414000
I/DynamiteModule(25851): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 202414000
V/DynamiteModule(25851): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/tter_hunte(25851): Unsupported class loader
W/tter_hunte(25851): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API(25851): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(25851): Google Play services package version: 202414022
W/tter_ufo_hunte(25851): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(25851): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/GoogleMapController(25851): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
D/HostConnection(25851): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc8220010, tid 25966
D/HostConnection(25851): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/eglCodecCommon(25851): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(25851): eglCreateContext: 0xd01be3c0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation(25851): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5385ba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe53838b0)
D/EGL_emulation(25851): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd01be3c0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xcb8e6410)
D/HostConnection(25851): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe3917360, tid 25864
D/HostConnection(25851): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
W/DynamiteModule(25851): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule(25851): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
I/DynamiteModule(25851): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/tter_hunte(25851): Unsupported class loader
W/tter_hunte(25851): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
D/HostConnection(25851): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc8220240, tid 25865
D/HostConnection(25851): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it looks like it was a simple issue with the AVD. I wiped the data and then it seems to work. Sorry to bother you with this!